# Reading a field from the code, working with the data, saving the values to new fileds in the row

Tags: php, mysql

So here is what I am doing.

1. Read a row each in for loop. (Because all at once is going to take some resources since I am in a shared hosting.)
   2.Get the right field data to a variable.
   3.Manipulate the req datas dependant on the extracted field.
   4.update the new fields where filed=extracted data.

Bit of addition, I am adding the current position to a file, so that the script can continue from there next time it is run.

Problem : It doesnt seem to work. The counter.txt gets values like 3-4, but it simply resides there. my db has like 1000k rows.

my code :

```
require ("dbconnect.php");
header("refresh:29;url=process.php"); // so it doesnt ever end. I cant use max_execution_time here for some reason.
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM collection ");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($count);
$count = $data[0];
echo $count;

$countfile = fopen("counter.txt", "r");
$counter = fgets($countfile);
echo fgets($countfile);

while (fgets($countfile) <= $count)
 {
$i = fgets($countfile);
$takeword = mysql_query("SELECT word FROM collection WHERE id='$i'") or die();
$wd = mysql_fetch_array($takeword);
$data = $wd[0];

$d1 = hash($algorith='md2',$data);
$d2 = hash($algorith='md4',$data);



$write = mysql_query("UPDATE collection SET md2='$d1', md4='$d2' WHERE id='$i'") or die(mysql_error());

//opens, empties and write the new pointer to the file. closes, and open the file in readmode for the next read at the loop.
$counts = fopen("counter.txt", "w+");
fwrite($counts, $counter + 1);
fclose($counts);
$countfile = fopen("counter.txt", "r");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :) Looking for code optimization and killing the error. Suggestions would do.:)

Comment: "Killing the error" are you getting an error? If so post it! :O

Comment: @Bono - I dont get any error messages, but I can see the value in the file not going up, neither the db gets filled up.

Comment: why are you reading and writing the counter to a file, and not using memory? very inefficient.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but this is really inefficent/badly designed. Also, fgets advances the stream by 1 line each time, you call it a bunch of time before you even start looping. When I get home I'll try decipher exactly what it is you want and write you an example.

Comment: @Dagon - Just incase the scripts gets killed due to any reasons, or if the database has more raw data that needs to be processed by this file, then it can start from the point it stopped.

As I said, I am all  ears for suggestions as I am just getting used it.

Comment: @JasonLarke - I am ok with constructive critism :) Will look forward for your example.

Comment: is this a rainbow table?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you basically just running through your DB and calculating the md2/md4 values for each 'word', then updating the row?

Comment: @Dagon - I am not exactly sure what a rainbow table is, WHat I am doing is storing the md2 and md4 of words from the db. Sounds like yes, its a rainbow table. But not sure if thats what it is called.

Comment: @JasonLarke - Running through the db picking `word` and updating the values to the fields `md2` and `md4`. Yes.

Comment: yup, and you download gigs of them already if you really want to. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table Little legit use, so i have no interest in helping any more.

Comment: @Dagon - Well, I am not working on this for Bruteforcing. lol. Thanks anyway. Had a read on that wiki page at the moment you mentioned Rainbow Table.

Comment: @JasonLarke - Any update on this Jason?

Comment: Completely forgot about this question, sorry. I'll try take a look at it soon.

Comment: @JasonLarke  Oh. Still waiting for your input on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I'd do something like this (sorry about the delayed response, I kept forgetting)

```
<?php
    //main execution
    $sql = mysql_connect(...);
    if (!$sql)
        die ("No database connection");

    if (!mysql_select_db(..., $sql))
        die ("Database does not exist in this schema");

    //Run the query for this iteration.
    processQuery();
    //---

    function getQueryOffset($file)
    {
        $offset = 0; //default offset
        if (file_exists($file)) //check if the counter file exists
        {
            $contents = file_get_contents($file); //get the contents of the counter
            if ($contents !== FALSE && is_numeric($contents)) //check if an appropriate counter value
                $offset = intval($contents);
        }
        return $offset;
    }

    function processQuery()
    {
        $table = "collection"; //table to update
        $counter = "counter.txt"; //where to look for the last execution's offset.
        $maxrows = 10000; //update 10,000 rows each time this file is loaded.
        $sql = $GLOBALS['sql'];

        //calculate the number of rows in the table
        $qCount = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) max FROM $table", $sql);
        $aCount = mysql_fetch_assoc($qCount);
        mysql_free_result($qCount);
        $max = $aCount["max"];

        $offset = getQueryOffset($counter); //calculate the offset (or a default 0)
        if ($offset < $max) //if offet >= max, we're done.
        {
            $qUpdate = mysql_query("SELECT word, id FROM $table LIMIT $offset, $maxrows", $sql); //get the next "maxrows" rows from the table.
            if ($qUpdate) 
            {
                $assoc = NULL;
                while (($assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($qUpdate)) != NULL)
                {
                    $md4 = hash("md4", $assoc["word"]); //calculate the hashes
                    $md2 = hash("md2", $assoc["word"]); 
                    $id = $assoc["id"]; //id the row
                    mysql_query("UPDATE $table SET md2='$md2', md4='$md4' WHERE id=$id", $sql); //update the table columns
                }
                //update the offset in the counter file.
                file_put_contents($counter, ($offset + mysql_num_rows($qUpdate)));
                mysql_free_result($qUpdate);
            }
        }
    }

    mysql_close($sql);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

1 issue that I am seeing here:

Check your update query - that seems to be wrong. According to me, it should be "SET md2='$d1' AND md4='$d2'"

Another issue that I am not sure about:

I am unsure if md2 and md4 are valid names of hashing algorithms

A better way of doing this:
1. Dont write to file!
2. Create an additional column in your SQL by the name 'status', default value to 0. On update, change that value to 1.
3. Search for rows to edit based on query "SELECT word FROM collection WHERE status=0 limit 0,1"
4. OR if the columns md2 and md4 are empty in the original table, query could also be "SELECT word FROM collection WHERE md2='' and md4='' limit 0,1"

Hope this helps.

Comment: I dont think and AND is needed in the update query. But I will make sure if it is needed.

And about setting a column for status, Imagine the program was killed at the point of 900k. So 900,001th row has status 0. So shouldnt the query go through all the rows till 900,001 before it actually starts working? :|

Comment: @Kishor  -no you only select rows that have status=0. SELECT word FROM collection WHERE id='$i' and status = 0; UPDATE collection SET md2='$d1', md4='$d2', status = '1' WHERE id='$i'

Comment: I am asking in that case, it simply queries the database until $i = 900,001. Isnt it?

Comment: simple solution to that problem - just put an index on "status"